# winform - login form template

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, forms, authentication, templates

new to winform development. I am trying to add a 'login form' to my project in vs2008 but the template is missing. When i do 'add new item', i don't see 'login form'. However i do see mainform, aboutbox form templates.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no template for 'Login Form' under C# unlike in VB.NET. So i created them manually in my C# project.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms apps assume you're using Windows authentication. If you need to provide a login, you'll have to code it yourself. Here's an example.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=499888

Comment: in vb.net, i can add form template 'login form' but my project is c# & i am not able to add login form. I understand i can write to check for authentication, however i want to be able to add the 'login form' in my c# project.